# How do I check that a varchar2 variable in PL/SQL is like 10 characters in a trigger?

Tags: variables, plsql, varchar2

How do I check that a varchar2 variable in PL/SQL is like 10 characters in a trigger?
And does it automatically proceed with the insert it its good?

```
--trigger that checks that number of characters are 10, doesnt work
create or replace trigger checkthings
before insert or update
on tblTenChars
declare
noGood exception;
begin
if :new.justTenVars(size) <> 10 then --this is not the way? 
raise noGood;
end if;
exception
when noGood then
raise_application_error(-20008, 'Wrong not 10 characters');
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a check constraint, not a trigger:

```
alter table tblTenChars add constraint checkthings
  check (length(justTenVars) = 10);
```

A check constraint is simpler and more efficient.

But for completeness, the trigger code would be:

```
create or replace trigger checkthings
before insert or update
on tblTenChars
for each row
begin
  if length(:new.justTenVars) <> 10 then 
    raise_application_error(-20008, 'Wrong not 10 characters');
  end if;
end;
```

If the exception is raised, the insert or update is aborted; otherwise it takes place.

Comment: Ok but what's the story on> for each row? When I have it compiles with errors when I don't have it doesn't compile due to 'not allowed with table-level-triggers'?

Comment: Allright, but i still have errors > 'PLS-00103: ...FOR when following where expected: begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier> <a double quoted delimited - identifer> current cursor delete exists prior'

Comment: Ok i got it, I couldnt have a declare part and and exception part. Cant you have declare variables and stuff in triggers?

Comment: Working: create or replace trigger checkthings
before insert or update
on tblTenChars
for each row
begin
if length(:new.justTenVars) <> 10 then
raise_application_error(-20008, 'Wrong not 10');
end if;
end;

Comment: Yes you can have `declare` - between `for each row` and `begin`

Comment: Not working> create or replace trigger checkthings
before insert or update
on tblTenChars
declare
nogood exception;
for each row
begin
if length(:new.justTenVars) <> 10 then
raise nogoodpass;
end if;
exception
when nogood then
raise_application_error(-20008, 'Wrong not 10');
end;